# ffplay fails to play certain files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpv

There are certain files that fails to play when I try to play them with `ffplay`. Here is the error they throw when trying to play,

```
❯ ffplay /usr/share/lmms/samples/instruments/harpsichord01.ogg
ffplay version n4.4 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig
--enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[wav @ 0x7f2660000c80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: none (Og[0][0] / 0x674F), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 144 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, wav, from '/usr/share/lmms/samples/instruments/harpsichord01.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:02.64, bitrate: 115 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: none (Og[0][0] / 0x674F), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 144 kb/s
No decoder could be found for codec none
Failed to open file '/usr/share/lmms/samples/instruments/harpsichord01.ogg' or configure filtergraph
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

This file is from the `DAW` `lmms`, incase anyone wants to try this particular file, just install `lmms` and it should in the same path. Apart from `ffplay` I have also tried playing this particular file with `gst-play-1.0`, `aplay`, and `mpv`. They all fail to play this file, however `Audacity` and some players like `Audcaious` plays this file fine. I'm wondering what is wrong here.

Comment: Nothing's wrong, `ffmpeg` does not support all existing audio codecs.

Comment: I see, what about `gst-play-1.0`, `aplay` and `mpv`, those doesn't support all audio codecs either?

Comment: The file is anomalous. The extension is ogg but the format is WAV (the first four bytes are RIFF whereas `.ogg` starts with OggS). The codec is vorbis for which ffmpeg has a native decoder. Forcing the vorbis decoder reveals the following warning: `Extradata corrupt`. Extradata, in ffmpeg parlance, is the codec configuration. This error seems to affect only this file in these folder of samples. So, I would just contact LMMS and ask them to provide a well-formed Ogg file.

Comment: mpv uses ffmpeg libraries, not sure about gst and aplay.